# How to select a tag by css selector

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm new in selenium. I'm trying to select one tag by css selector by there is a mistake somewhere.

```
<li class="arr-r active">
<a class="sem" alt="Alter" href="/something.html" data-page="2"><span>2</span></a>
</li>
```

I've tried many options but none of it works.

```
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li.arr-r.active.a').click()
```

Could you give me a hint where the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

`a` is not a class; Remove a dot before `a` element.

```
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li.arr-r.active a').click()
```

or

```
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li.arr-r.active>a').click()
```

Comment: +1 over the other answer for the introduction of `>`.  many selenium (well, css) beginners are unaware of the difference between `>` and " " (child vs descendent)

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('li.arr-r.active a').click()
```

"a" is not a class, is a tag. So you should not put a dot before "a".